# How to reroute line-in of one sound card to line-out of another one on LINUX

Tags: linux, audio, sound-card, alsa

Well, what the title says. I want to reroute the line-in (mic) of an on-board soundcard, to the line-out of a USB-connected one - ON LINUX. I have tried with JACK2 and `jack_connect` but *I think* it works only with the ports of the same sound card. Right now I am experimenting with `alsa_in` + `alsa_out`, but I've read a lot about delay and reliability issues with this approach. Is this pretty much it?